# How to remove PrimeNG dropdown icon?

Tags: css, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using PrimeNG dropdown and was trying to remove the dropdown toggle icon. I've tried using css, but still doesn't work, maybe I am doing it wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your CSS is overwritten by PrimeNG itself. You have to load yours after it.

This should do the trick :

```
.ui-dropdown-trigger {
  display: none;
}
```

See `styles.css` file in that [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-g13d5i).

Answer (score 0):

You can use primeng build-in property:

```
[dropdownIcon]="'none'"
```